# 2d matrix, second diagonal. list index out of range python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix

I'm tring to get the second diagonal in a matrix.
For example:

```
123
456
789
```

I want to get 357
and sum them

```
 for l in range(len(arr)):
        z+=arr[l][len(arr)-l]

 #arr is the matrix
```

I get the error:list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you do 
`for l in range(len(arr)):`
the `l` starts from 0.
So at the first loop, `arr[l][len(arr)-l]` is actually `arr[0][3]` which is out of index since the max index is `arr[2][2]`.
You should change it to

```
 for l in range(len(arr)):
        z+=arr[l][len(arr)-1-l]
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was thinking that len(arr) = 2.